# Php preg_match_all function to find a version pattern

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I am trying to get the version info from a file that contains the line:

[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.1")]

I need to get 1.0.0.1

The function i have tried something like following:

```
preg_match_all('/[assembly: AssemblyVersion("([^,">]+).*?")/')
```

But no matches returned with this function.

What is the correct way to get version info in this example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code does not appear to even be working.  The main problem, from what I can see, is that you are not escaping literal parentheses and square brackets.  After making that change, it seems to work:

```
$input = "blah blah blah [assembly: AssemblyVersion(\"1.0.0.1\")] blah";
preg_match_all('/\[assembly: AssemblyVersion\("([^,">]+).*?"\)\]/', $input, $array);
print_r($array[1]);

Array
(
    [0] => 1.0.0.1
)
```

Comment: I have missed the escape characters, thank you.  As questlooking mentioned, it may be messed up while working with complicated regex expression.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex :

```
$line='[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.1")]';

    preg_match_all("/(?<=\[assembly: AssemblyVersion\(\").*(?=\"\))]/",$line,$matches);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can solve problem without regex - **you have to do it**. Because this functions are very heavy and unpredictable .

For example, just split string by double quotes (if string has a strict format):

```
$parts = explode('"', '[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.1")]');
echo $parts[1];
```